# How to split a string by dash at specific position JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I have a dynamically created array as below:

```
["171281-0-001-1", "171281-0-001-2"]
```

Basically, I am creating the value based on a very complex function. But that function does not matter here. Basically for example `171281-0-001-1` is made of Account number + id. `171281-0-001` is Account number and `1` is the id.
The number of dashes can be any number but after the last dash it's always id.
How can I differentiate these from my value and assign it into different variables?

Tried:

```
for (let key in this.your_reference) {
  extractedAccountNumber = key.split('-')[0];
  extractedId = key.split('-')[1];
}
```

But since the dashes can be in any number now, the variables have wrong values.  Any idea guys? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map()` and `split()` to take the item from the last array *index*:

```js
var arr = ["171281-0-001-1", "171281-0-001-2"];
var idList = arr.map(d => {
  d = d.split('-');
  return d[d.length - 1];
});
console.log(idList);
```

Comment: but how about the first item? i need to keep the other value as it is

Comment: @chewi, you can use new variable to hold the result returned by the function....updated the answer.....thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression with two groups: one captured group, which matches anything, then *match* a dash, then another captured group for digits followed by the end of the string:

```js
["171281-0-001-1", "171281-0-001-2"].forEach((str) => {
  // first item in the array is the entire match,
  // but you only care about the two capture groups, so ignore the first item:
  const [,accountNumber, id] = str.match(/(.+)-(\d+)$/);
  console.log(accountNumber);
  console.log(id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) and [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) for that:

```js
var arr = ["171281-0-001-1", "171281-0-001-2"];
var ids = arr.map(d => d.substring(d.lastIndexOf('-') + 1));
console.log(ids);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = ["171281-0-001-1", "171281-0-001-2"];

const accountDetails = arr.map((item) => {
  const itemArr = item.split('-');
  const accountNumber = itemArr.slice(0, itemArr.length -1).join('-');
  const id = itemArr[itemArr.length - 1];

  return {id, accountNumber};
});

console.log(accountDetails);
```